# How to catch mouse motion event in some ceratin area of a component?

Tags: java

I use a Jlayered pane with 4 layers and put in each layer a colored label to distinguish one from another. The layers do not completely overlap. I want each time the mouse move to a layer, something happens like the layer change color. How I can make my program detect which layer the mouse is on and react accordingly?

Comment: swt, swing, awt? What graphical library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Swing, if each layer is a panel or some other kind of swing component, you can add a MouseListener to the panel or layer.

```
// Add a MouseListener to every individual layer
layer.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
         // This method will be fired each time the mouse enters the layer
         // So any code here will execute when the mouse enters said layer
         // Which means you could put code here to change the color, etc.
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

});
```

If you want more information on the topic, you can read a tutorial on how to write a MouseListener from Oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Or even watch a video on how to create a MouseListener. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpIHF4V3zMc